# Iam trying to automate the code using selenium python in pytest framework facing the Attribute error issue

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, pytest

def setUserName(self, username):

> ```
>   self.driver.find_element(By.ID, self.textbox_Username_ID).send_keys(username)
> ```

E       AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_element'

AttributeError

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You did not initialize `driver` object properly, currently it is not existing, `'NoneType'` in Python

Comment: How to initiate help me .

Comment: Please share all your code

Comment: @pytest.fixture(scope="class")
def setup(request):
    ser = Service("path")  # /usr/local/bin/chromedriver
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ser)
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    driver.maximize_window()
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
    driver.get("url")
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    driver.maximize_window()
    request.cls.driver = driver
    request.cls.wait = wait
    yield
    driver.close()
    driver.quit()

Comment: No, not here. In the question itself. make it readable